# Can a MATLAB function take mathematical functions as inputs?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, symbolic-math

I am totally new to this site and MATLAB, so please excuse me if my question is naive or a duplicate of some already existing question.

Well, I am a mathematics student, using MATLAB to aid in my project. There is a thing call "L^2 inner product" in which you need 2 mathematical functions, says f(x) and g(x), as inputs. It should work like

> inner(f,g)=integrat f(x)*g(x) from 0 to 1.

The problem is I don't know how to write that in MATLAB.

To summarize, I want to make a *MATLAB function* whose inputs are two *mathematical functions*, the output is a real number. I know how to make an inline object but I don't know how to proceed further. Any help would be highly appreciated.

PS. I don't know if my tags are appropriate or on topic or not, please bear with me.

Comment: you can do it quite easily using an anonymous function even. e.g., `inner = @(f,g) integral(@(x) f(x)*g(x),0,1)`

Comment: See the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/pass-a-function-to-another-function.html)

Comment: @transversalitycondition Thank you! It seems to be working fine when f,g are inline objects. Suppose that I create a function 
>function ans=Func(vector,x)

and I want to find inner(Func,Func) with respect to "x" for a fixed "vector", how do I do it in this case?

Comment: @BigbearZzz if I understand your question correctly, you just need to use anonymous functions again. E.g., `inner = @(f,g,vector) integral(@(x) f(x,vector).*g(x,vector),0,1)`

Answer (score 1):

I will build on what @transversality condition wrote in greater detail (eg. there should be a .*)

#### Illustrative example with anonymous functions

```
h = @sin % This assigns h the function handle of the sin function
         % If you know c, c++, this is basically a function pointer

inner = @(f,g)integral(@(x)f(x).*g(x),0,1) % This assigns  the variable inner
                                           % the function hanlde of a function which 
                                           % takes in two function handles f and g
                                           % and calculates the integral from 0 to 1
                         % Because of how Matlab works, you want .* here;
                         % you need f and g to be fine with vector inputs.

inner(h, @cos)           %this will calculate $\int_0^1 sin(x)cos(x)dx$
```

This yields 0.354

#### Writing inner as a regular function

In the previous example, inner was a variable, and the value of the variable was a function handle to a function which calculates the inner product. You could also just write a function that calculates the inner product. Create a file `myinner.m` with the following code:

```
function y = myinner(f, g)
y = integral(@(x)f(x).*g(x),0,1);
```

You could then call myinner the same way:

```
myinner(@sin, @cos)
```

result: 0.354

Note also that the `integral` function calculates the integral numerically and in strange situations, it's possible to have numerical problems.